# Cannot compile. No space left on device error - Unix

Tags: unix

I'm coding for class and when I try to compile I now get this error. Worked fine yesterday. IT does not work weekends so I'm out of luck until Monday unless someone can help. I'm fairly new to unix as I only really use it when coding.

```
cc scheduler.c 
Close failure on scheduler.o : No space left on device
cc: acomp failed for scheduler.c
```

Comment: ummm...your hard drive is full

Comment: Type in [`df -H`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?df) to see your device storage use/availability :|

Comment: Working in ssh so on a school server. Am I looking for paths that are at 100%? and then what, just delete if I can?

Comment: `df -H .` will show the usage for the filesystem containing the current directory, which is probably the only one you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Delete some things on your disk. Use df (type 'man df' for usage) to see where the mount point is that you're compiling onto.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `quota` command. It'll show you how much space you get. You've probably just used up all the disk space you're allotted for you account. Go to your home directory:

```
> cd ~
```

and run:

```
> du -sh *
```

It will show how much space each of your directories takes up. Just remove some unused files.

If one directory takes up most of the space, you can `cd` into it and run `du -sh *` there too, to see the disk usage of its subdirectories.  It's basically just a useful command for finding large files that you might not need anymore.  For example, if you downloaded a really big program for a class project last year, but no longer need it, just `rm` it.